# IHow to execute the content of xmlhttp.responsText

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a function which gets the

```
xmlhttp.responsText
```

The content of this is a javascript code like

```
setChatter('".$name."');showHideLayer('chatFenster');return(false);
```

How can I execute this javacode which I get from the xmlhttp response ?

Thank you very very much guys =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use
    eval(xmlhttp.responseText);